# How to get click event when libraries like fastclick, jQuery mobile and ngTouch (angular) are loaded in page for touch devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to capture all the clicks happened in document using pure JavaScript. For that I have attached this listener in page at runtime.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(){ console.log('clicked!') }, true);
```

But when some libraries like fastclick is loaded in page, it prevents the following click event from propagating. So for such cases click callback function won't be fired.

There are so many libraries like ngTouch for angular, jQuery mobile and so on who do the same..

Now my question is is there any way through which i came to know that any element is clicked. I can bind touchstart or touchend event on document. But that is not sufficient for me. I want to make sure about element click. As sometimes it may be possible that I get touchend event but not click.

Comment: [fiddle, please](http://jsfiddle.net)